# How to raise an event from shortcut key of an active or selected object?

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a UserCotrol named ***DGridView*** composed of a DatagridView and a MenuStrip with 2 buttons for adding ***tsAddRow*** and deleting rows ***tsDeleteRow***. I assigned a shortcut key for the buttons (Ctrl + Insert) and (Ctrl + Delete) respectively.

Here's a part my code for my usercontrol with regards to the buttons:

```
Public Event ItemClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

Private Sub tsItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsDeleteRow.Click, tsAddRow.Click
    RaiseEvent ItemClick(sender, e)
End Sub
```

Then on another Form named ***Form1***, I used my usercontrol DGridView 3 times for my child tables, ex. ***DGrid_1***, ***DGrid_2*** and ***DGrid_3***. 
Here's my code for the event catcher inside Form1.

```
Private Sub DGrid_1_ItemClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DGrid_1.ItemClick
    'do code
End Sub

Private Sub DGrid_2_ItemClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DGrid_2.ItemClick
    'do code
End Sub

Private Sub DGrid_3_ItemClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DGrid_3.ItemClick
    'do code
End Sub
```

Ofcourse those 3 objects will have the same shortcut keys for Add and Delete Row. How can I determined which one fired the shortcut key? For example, DGrid_2 is Active then I used the shortcut for Add key (Ctrl + Insert). How will I do the code to add rows on ***DGrid_2***? My current code was Adding rows on the first object ***DGrid_1***.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it, though it could get a little messy if not done correctly, is to set a class level boolean.

Example

```
Public Class myClass

Dim isActive As Boolean
```

Then, when clicking on, or activating `DGrid_1`, set `isActive = True`, then when activating the other (or deactivating `DGrid_1`), set `isActive = False`.

That way, you can check the value of the boolean.

```
If isActive = True Then
  ' Code for DGrid_1
ElseIf isActive = False Then
  ' Code for DGrid_2
End If
```

There may be easier ways, heck, there may even be a `DataGridView.IsActive` type method, but off the top of my head and without an IDE available, this is one way to go about it.

**EDIT**

Or, additionally, I believe there is something along the lines of

```
Dim sName as String = Me.ActiveControl.Name
' Above may need a Convert.ToString, not sure off the top of my head
```

Then, you can compare the value of `sName` and determine which control to use then.

Answer (score 0):

Change what you set as the `sender` when you raise the event. The `sender` is used to indicate what object that raised an event, thus you can use that to determine which one of your user controls caught the key press.

```
Private Sub tsItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsDeleteRow.Click, tsAddRow.Click
    RaiseEvent ItemClick(Me, e) 'Me is the current user control.
End Sub
```

Then in your form:

```
Private Sub DGrid_ItemClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DGrid_1.ItemClick, DGrid_2.ItemClick, DGrid_3.ItemClick
    Dim TargetGrid As DGridView = TryCast(sender, DGridView)
    If TargetGrid IsNot Nothing Then 'Casting succeeded.
        TargetGrid.DoYourStuff()
    End If
End Sub
```

If you want to check specifically which instance raised the event and do different stuff for each, you can check the sender's reference as well:

```
Private Sub DGrid_ItemClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DGrid_1.ItemClick, DGrid_2.ItemClick, DGrid_3.ItemClick
    Dim TargetGrid As DGridView = TryCast(sender, DGridView)
    If TargetGrid IsNot Nothing Then 'Casting succeeded.

        If TargetGrid Is DGrid_1 Then
            'Do stuff for DGrid_1.
        ElseIf TargetGrid Is DGrid_2 Then
            'Do stuff for DGrid_2.
        ElseIf TargetGrid Is DGrid_3 Then
            'Do stuff for DGrid_3.
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```